# Passing a "String" Object into a DJB2 hash function

Tags: c++, string, hash

I was using the standard char * version of the djb2 hash function:

```
unsigned long(unsigned char *str){
    unsigned long hash = 5381;
    int c;

    while (c = *str++)
        hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) + c; /* hash * 33 + c */
    }
```

How could I edit this hash function to accept a String object instead of an unsigned char*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a string instead?

```
unsigned long DJB2(std::string str){
    unsigned long hash = 5381;
    int c;

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i) {
        c = (int) str[i];
        hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) + c; 
    }
    return hash;
}
```